# Pickling routines accessible through the C API?

Tags: python, api, pickle

I would like to call Python's pickling routines (`dumps` and `loads`) from within c++ code. Are they exposed in the official API? I am currently calling those via boost::python from c++, looking for a simpler way perhaps.

Comment: I do not think they can be "exposed" any more than that, they need a running interpreter, you can get the PyObject*s for `dumps` and `loads` and then call them yourselves using the C-API?

Comment: There is also [How can I read a python pickle database/file from C?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1296162)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many years later, not quite answering the question, and based on Martijn Pieters' answer, here is a drop in replacement for Marshal:

```
static PyObject * PyPickle=NULL;
static PyObject * pDumps=NULL;
static PyObject * pLoads=NULL;

static void init_pickle()
{
    if(!pDumps)
        pDumps = PyUnicode_FromString("dumps");
    if(!pLoads)
        pLoads = PyUnicode_FromString("loads");

    if(!PyPickle)
        PyPickle = PyImport_ImportModule("pickle");
}

static PyObject *PyPickle_ReadObjectFromString(const char *data, Py_ssize_t len)
{
    PyObject *pstr = PyBytes_FromStringAndSize(data, len);
    PyObject *ret=NULL;

    ret = PyObject_CallMethodOneArg(PyPickle, pLoads, pstr);
    Py_XDECREF(pstr);

    return ret;
}

static PyObject *PyPickle_WriteObjectToString(PyObject *value, int version)
{
    //version currently ignored
    return PyObject_CallMethodOneArg(PyPickle, pDumps, value);
}
```

Perhaps someone will find it useful.

Answer (score 3):

You can call *any* Python code through the C API:

```c
static PyObject *module = NULL;
PyObject *pickle;

if (module == NULL &&
    (module = PyImport_ImportModuleNoBlock("pickle")) == NULL)
    return NULL;
```

now, you can either call it like:

[python-2.x](/questions/tagged/python-2.x)

```c
pickle = PyObject_CallMethodObjArgs(module,
                                    PyString_AS_STRING("dumps"),
                                    py_object_to_dump,
                                    NULL);
```

[python-3.x](/questions/tagged/python-3.x)

```c
pickle = PyObject_CallMethodObjArgs(module,
                                    PyUnicode_FromString("dumps"),
                                    py_object_to_dump,
                                    NULL);
```

or like:

```c
picle = PyObject_CallMethod(module, "dumps", "O", py_object_to_dump);
```

and then do the error checking and clean up:

```
if (pickle != NULL) { ... }
Py_XDECREF(pickle);
```

but in the case of `pickle` you can just use the [`cPickle` functions](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2b8c5ed7b38b/Modules/cPickle.c) directly. The only problem there is that the `cPickle` module (or `_pickle` in Python 3) is statically compiled into the Python binary, or needs to be loaded separately. Using the Python import mechanisms is simply easier here.

Comment: Thanks, I do call Python through the C API (wrapped in boost::python), but I was hoping to call the pickling functions "directly".

Comment: @eudoxos: are you using Python 2 or 3? The C module was renamed to [`_pickle`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.4/Modules) in Python 3. It depends a little on wether or not the `cPickle` module has been statically compiled or needs to be dynamically loaded here too.

Comment: I want to support both actually. I import _pickle for py3k and cPickle for py2k.

Comment: @eudoxos: it's easiest to just use import here rather than have to figure out if you can use the functions directly or not.

Answer (score 1):

Complementing the other C-API-based answer by @aflin, this would be in c++ using pybind11 (and the C-API underneath):

Header file:

```cpp
#include<string>
#include<pybind11/pybind11.h>
namespace py=pybind11;

class Pickler{
    static bool initialized;
    static py::handle cPickle_dumps;
    static py::handle cPickle_loads;
    static void ensureInitialized();
    public:
        static std::string dumps(py::object o);
        static py::object loads(const std::string&);
};
```

Implementation:

```cpp
py::handle Pickler::cPickle_dumps;
py::handle Pickler::cPickle_loads;
bool Pickler::initialized=false;

void Pickler::ensureInitialized(){
    if(initialized) return;
    py::gil_scoped_acquire pyLock;
    py::object cPickle=py::module::import("pickle");
    cPickle_dumps=cPickle.attr("dumps");
    cPickle_loads=cPickle.attr("loads");
    initialized=true;
}

std::string Pickler::dumps(py::object o){
    ensureInitialized();
    py::gil_scoped_acquire pyLock;
    py::object minus1=py::cast(-1);
    // watch out! the object might have NULL pointer (uninitialized??) so make sure to pass None in that case
    PyObject *b=PyObject_CallFunctionObjArgs(cPickle_dumps.ptr(),o.ptr()?o.ptr():Py_None,minus1.ptr(),NULL);
    if(!b){
        if(PyErr_Occurred()) throw py::error_already_set();
        else throw std::runtime_error("Pickling failed but no python error was set??");
    }
    assert(PyBytes_Check(b));
    return std::string(py::reinterpret_steal<py::bytes>(b));
}
py::object Pickler::loads(const std::string& s){
    ensureInitialized();
    py::gil_scoped_acquire pyLock;
    return cPickle_loads(py::handle(PyBytes_FromStringAndSize(s.data(),(Py_ssize_t)s.size())));
}
```

And then, obviously, calling `Pickler::dumps(...)` or `Pickler::loads(...)` in your code.