# How to (de-)serialize PyObject* in C(++)?

Tags: python, c, serialization, python-c-api

I'm currently working on a multi-threaded python module in C(++). I'm almost done, but one of the last things I need to do is to find a way around the GIL, so that communication between threads becomes possible.

To do this, I wish to attempt the following pseudo code:

```
// Called from Python
Pyobject* send_data(data, procid) {
    // Change the Python object to byte data and 
    // store it outside of python's memory management.
    serialized = serialize(data);

    // Send the byte data to desired processor
    // (Stored in a queue on that processor)
    send(serialize, procid);
}

// Called from python
Pyobject* receive_data() {
    // Grab data from queue
    serialized = grab_data();

    // De-serialize data
    data = de_serialize(serialized);

    return data;
}
```

The reason I wish to serialize the data before sending is due to the fact that the memory size of the sent data has to be known. Since `sizeof(PyObject*) = 8`, this is my attempt to ensure the size is always correct.

Now, I found a way to serialize the data in python using [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/pickle.html), but don't know how I could transfer this to C in a manner that is computationally acceptable. (So without calling a function which starts a python instance, imports the right library and sends the pickle function as a callable to C.)

Any help in achieving this would be hugely appreciated!

Of course, if you know how to get accurate size data from the PyObjects and know how to clone them to C, that would also be great! ^_^'

Comment: I think using pickle is a good idea. Why would something like this not work? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28693433/pickling-routines-accessible-through-the-c-api

Comment: If you're touching generic `PyObject`s in *any way*, then you cannot work around the GIL, period.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala So you're telling me that there is no way at all to store a python object (e.g. int, list or np array) in some form which allows C to duplicate that memory and send it to another processor without registering to the GIL?

Comment: @MitchellFaas yes it is possible to send the data in *a* PyObject, if *you* manage it somehow taking all the precautions. Not *any* Python object. Usually it means that you wrote all the code for it, and it can be ever manipulated through the code that you've written...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're after handling serialised data in two separate languages, how about a language-agnostic serialisation standard? This means a schema first approach.

This is the best approach to avoid writing every data structure definition twice, once in C and once in Python, particularly useful if you have complicated data structures.

For both Python and C, the choices are a bit thin. There's Google Protocol Buffers [here](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/) and [C version here](https://github.com/protobuf-c/protobuf-c), Apache Avro [here](http://avro.apache.org/docs/current/) will probably work too, and ASN.1 (if you're feeling brave [overview](https://www.thanassis.space/asn1.html), [recommended reference](http://www.oss.com/asn1/resources/books-whitepapers-pubs/dubuisson-asn1-book.PDF), [Playground](http://asn1-playground.oss.com/), [Commercial](https://www.obj-sys.com/products/), [Commercial](http://www.oss.com/), and take a look on GitHub for some free ones).

The general approach with all of these is to generate Python, C (or C#, Java, C++) source code from a schema. The source code defines data structures, and the functions / methods required to serialise / deserialise those to a common wireformat. The output / input to these functions is an array of bytes, so their content is not going to involve the GIL when used on the C side.

With mature tools that work properly, this is a very liberating way of exchanging data; you can mix languages in a system as required. ASN.1 in particular is very good, as its constraints system allows one to be very specific about what is, and what is not, valid data. Strong interfaces! Google Protocol Buffers is almost perfect (because it's free and does almost everything), but has no constraints.

If you have only simple data structures, the overhead of writing every structure definition twice might not be so bad. So any decent Pickle library for C might do nicely, so long as they don't just build a Python object from the Pickle.

Comment: With Christmas going on, I can't spend a lot on time on trying to understand your comment before responding, so I apologize for any misunderstanding in advance. That said, I don't really grasp why one would have to write the data structure in C, too. All C is responsible for is communicating a certain number of bytes at a certain memory address. C won't have to be able to understand any of the information in this memory, just transfer it to another core. Python then needs to be able to read the data again and store it.

Comment: @MitchellFaas, no worries, and seasons greetings :-) My point is that with the python object serialised, and deserialised in C++, you're then free to do whatever one wishes with the data in C++ as it now lives outside of the the Python interpretter, and the GIL can't touch it. As you'd now have a C++ equivalent object (courtesy of the deserialisation), you'd be having to process the data in C++, not Python.

Comment: I see. I think that's a great way around the problem I'm having! Happy holidays to you too :)