# Port XGBoost model trained in python to another system written in C/C++

Tags: python, machine-learning, xgboost

Suppose I have successfully trained a XGBoost machine learning model in python.

```
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=7)
model = XGBClassifier()
model.fit(x_train, y_train)
y_pred = model.predict(x_test)
```

I want to port this model to another system which will be writte in C/C++. To do this, I need to know the internal logic of the XGboost trained model and translate them into a series of if-then-else statements like decision trees, if I am not wrong.

How can this be done? How to find out the internal logic of the XGBoost trained model to implement it on another system?

I am using python 3.7.

Comment: Another way of thinking about this question is: "How can I serialize/deserialize the model in a format that both languages can understand?" Pickling may be the answer. This answer has a few potential options: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296162/how-can-i-read-a-python-pickle-database-file-from-c

Comment: This does something similar, but doesn't yet offer C++ output: https://github.com/modusdatascience/sklearn2code.  C++ could be added with a little work.

Comment: have you been able to find what's the internal logic of XGBoost models?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[m2cgen](https://github.com/BayesWitnesses/m2cgen) Is an awesome package that will convert Scikit-Learn compatible models into raw code. If you are using XGBoosts sklearn wrappers (which it looks like you are), then you can simply call something like this:

```
model = XGBClassifier()
model.fit(x_train, y_train)
 ...
import m2cgen as m2c

with open('./model.c','w') as f:
    code = m2c.export_to_c(model)
    f.write(code)
```

The really awesome thing about this package, is that it supports many different types of models, such as

- Linear
- SVM
- Tree
- Random Forest
- Boosting

One more thing. m2cgen also supports multiple languages such as

- C
- C#
- Dart
- Go
- Haskell
- Java
- JavaScript
- PHP
- PowerShell
- Python
- R
- Visual Basic

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 7):

Someone wrote a script that does exactly this. Check out https://github.com/popcorn/xgb2cpp

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way of using any ml/dl model is making simple RESTful API with flask/bottle (these are lightweight python frameworks) and use them globally with any language.

You can also containerize RESTful API with docker in case you are developing a big project with a lot of models.
Even containerized Restful APIs are used to deploy models on the cloud, ex- aws.

If you are interested in getting the logic behind any ml model, always have a look on its source code (on GitHub).