# Do xgboost models tend to be large in size (MB on disk)?

Tags: python, xgboost

I have been playing with XGBoost (specifically, the XGBRegressor) in Python. I used it to create a model with 200 estimators, max_depth of 14. It was trained on about 2M training data points. It only has 3 features and 1 output.
The model is extremely accurate and I also checked it was not overfitting. But, when I save the model, it is huge! It takes up 160 MB on disk, and when I convert it to C (using Treelite) it is 490 MB on disk.
I have to finally deploy it in machines without python, and it has to interface with another software which can only load C files. Such a huge size is a major implementation challenge.

Is there something I am not doing right? Or do xgboost models typically this large? I have looked around on the web, but haven't been able to find this issue.

I am using Python 3.7 and Anaconda to build my models. I am not sure what other details I should post.

Comment: Yes. Having a large number of estimators and a high `max_depth` can create large models in my experience. I would try lowering the max depth as much as possible (without sacrificing accuaracy). For converting to `C` take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61468101/13253198)

Comment: One more thing. 200 estimators may be  overkill. You could try increasing the learning rate and decreasing the number of estimators. This has worked well for me in the past.

Comment: Thanks gnodab. The max_depth came out of an exhaustive grid search in the vicinity of 14. I thought an early stop in the xgboost model should stop the n_estimators if accuracy wasn't improving. But this is good information. I will see how much room I have for sacrificing accuracy to get the model in a reasonable shape.

Comment: You may not sacrifice any accuracy. In fact it is possible that it improves on your test/validation hold out set. Also, even though the model is very large. After porting to `C` it is still extremely fast.