# Port XGBoost model with m2cgen: presence of nan

Tags: python, machine-learning, xgboost

I got into the same situation as the OP of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58143075/port-xgboost-model-trained-in-python-to-another-system-written-in-c-c). I would definitely prefer just to see the doc on how to extract the data from the xgb model and how exactly to code up its forward propagation, but m2cgen sounded like a good alternative. I used the following code

```
import xgboost as xgb
import seaborn as sns
import m2cgen as m2c

df = sns.load_dataset("diamonds")

X = df.drop(['cut', 'color', 'clarity', 'price'], axis = 1)
y = df.price

n = X.shape[0]
n_split = int(n*0.75)

model = xgb.XGBRegressor(objective ='reg:squarederror', 
                         max_depth = 2, 
                         n_estimators = 1,
                         eval_metric="rmse")
model.fit(X, y)

with open('./diamonds_model.c','w') as f:
    code = m2c.export_to_c(model)
    f.write(code)
```

and as a result I see

```
double score(double * input) {
    double var0;
    if (input[0] >= 0.995) {
        if (input[4] >= 7.1949997) {
            var0 = 3696.243;
        } else {
            var0 = 1841.0602;
        }
    } else {
        if (input[4] >= 5.535) {
            var0 = 922.34973;
        } else {
            var0 = 317.401;
        }
    }
    return nan + var0;
}
```

So I wonder what am I doing wrong and where does this nan come from. I'm on python 3.8.5 and xgb prints version 1.7.3

Answer (score 1):

The NaN component of the `nan + var0` expression likely corresponds to XGBoost's `base_score` parameter (aka "global bias" aka intercept). It appears to be unset for your `XGBRegressor` instance, hence it is emitted as the default (NaN) value.

Try setting the `base_score` value manually to `0`:

```py
model = xgb.XGBRegressor(base_score = 0, ...)
```

This issue seems to affect newer XGBoost versions. See also [m2cgen-581](https://github.com/BayesWitnesses/m2cgen/issues/581).