# numpy pickle data exchange with C++ Eigen or std::vector

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, c++11, pickle

I am writing numpy data to sqlite database with pickling.

Is there anyway to read this pickle from c++ to EigenMatrix or std::vector ?

Best

Answer (score 0):

You can either use [Boost Libraries](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_33_1/libs/python/doc/v2/pickle.html) or the specifically designed cross-language library [Picklingtools](http://www.picklingtools.com/).

**Edit:** you can find an example to the latter one on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296162/how-can-i-read-a-python-pickle-database-file-from-c).