# How to Load Machine Learning Models in C that was built and trained in Python (eg. SciKit-Learn)?

Tags: python, c, machine-learning

After I build a Machine Learning Model in Python, train it and save it (dump it to file), I want to load the trained model in my C program and run it to get it's predictions in my C program.  Is there a C library that allows me to load ML models and run predictions in my C program ?

Comment: The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296162/how-can-i-read-a-python-pickle-database-file-from-c) might be helpful for you.

Comment: you could try something like [neonrvm](https://siavashserver.github.io/neonrvm/predict.html)